# C++ Destroying a child window

Tags: c++, windows

I'm have a problem closing my child window, and would greatly appreciate some directions on how to solve my problem.

I use the following code to create the window, which succesfully creates and shows the child window.

```
 hwndComboBoxLang = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, TEXT(""), 
 CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE ,
 xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight, hwnd, NULL, hThisInstance,
 NULL);
```

And this to destroy the window:

```
DestroyWindow(DW.hwndComboBoxLang);
```

- The function is being reached, as I have tested it out by succesfully destroying the "child" window when the WS_CHILD parameter is removed, and succesfully used the function on the parent window. I am also unable to succesfully use the ShowWindow(DW.hwndComboBoxLang, SW_HIDE); function on the child window.

I have not registered the child window, as I assume its derived from the registered parent class therefore this is not nessecary, is this assumption wrong? Is the child window created but is the handle pointing towards nothing?

Can you point me in the right direction on how to correctly close a child window?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If DestroyWindow() fails, you can use GetLastError() to see the reason why.  Please do a check on the return value and the error code and add that to your question.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What is the question? Are you saying that your DestroyWindow function isn't getting called, or are you saying that ShowWindow is not working.  Can you post a minimal, but complete example of code?

Comment: check the handle that is passed; also, compare it with the real handle of the box - from spy++

Comment: Step 1 is to learn to check Windows API calls for errors. So, to be 100% clear, whenever you call a Windows API function, check for errors. Posting long questions like this without including the return value and the error code is utterly pointless. Obviously it looks like the window handle is duff. Since that's the only thing you pass to `DestroyWindow`, how else could it fail?

Comment: Thank you all for your reply,

After reading the return value of GetLastError() (1400 ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE), I managed to find the problem.

The function DestroyWindow was called in the WindowProc function of the parent window. after adding EnumChildWindows the child window closed perfectly fine.